# Combining two queries in one

Tags: php, sql, t-sql

What I want is getting all names (first, middle, last) of the users along with each of their total hours of work which will be calculated by the SQL statement: `CAST(SUM(timediff(dateTimeOut,dateTimeIn) as time)`.

I was able to achieve this with two queries, but somehow, I feel that this is inefficient (?):

```
$sql = "SELECT id, firstName, middleName, lastName FROM users_info";
$result = $pdo->query($sql);

$rows = array();

while($row = $result->fetch()){
     $time = $pdo->query(
                "SELECT CAST(SUM(timediff(dateTimeOut, dateTimeIn)) 
                 as time) as totalHoursWorked
                 FROM users_time WHERE user_id = {$row['id']}"
            )->fetch();

     $row['totalHoursWorked'] = $time['totalHoursWorked'];
     $rows[] = $row;

}

echo json_encode($rows);
```

I'll use the json data for a DataTable.

```
users_info table
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
| id | firstName | middleName | lastName |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+
|  1 | Isabelle  | Luna       | Ibarra   |
|  2 | George    | Boston     | Everett  |
|  3 | Skyler    | Land       | Cohen    |
+----+-----------+------------+----------+


users_time table:
+---------+---------+---------------------+--------------------+
| time_id | user_id |     dateTimeIn      |    dateTimeOut     |
+---------+---------+---------------------+--------------------+
|       1 |       1 | 2019-06-14 00:00:00 | 2019-06-16 09:00:0 |
|       2 |       1 | 2019-06-15 00:00:00 | 2019-06-16 08:00:0 |
|       3 |       2 | 2019-06-14 00:00:00 | 2019-06-16 09:30:0 |
|       4 |       2 | 2019-06-15 00:00:00 | 2019-06-16 08:30:0 |
|       5 |       3 | 2019-06-16 00:00:00 | 2019-06-16 09:00:0 |
+---------+---------+---------------------+--------------------+
```

db-fiddle link : https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vpozKbVoXxPoGzcsBkLL36/0

Comment: Could you provide us the DDL and insert statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that the id's in `users_info` exist in `users_time`, INNER JOIN (or just JOIN) is the way to merge the tables.  If id's in `user_info` might not exist in `users_time` then use LEFT JOIN to allow `null` values in `totalHoursWorked`.

Assuming you want all four columns' data to be included in your echo'ed json string (your posted code isn't do that), you can just `fetchAll()` directly into your `json_encode()` and echo it -- all at once.

SQL: ([Demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uqWbJAgpHc3hVTPt6Xqomf/0))

```
$sql = "SELECT i.id,
            MAX(i.firstName),
            MAX(i.middleName),
            MAX(i.lastName),
            CAST(SUM(TIMEDIFF(t.dateTimeOut, t.dateTimeIn)) AS TIME) AS totalHoursWorked
        FROM users_info i
        INNER JOIN users_time t ON i.id = t.user_id
        GROUP BY i.id";
$query = $pdo->query($sql);
echo json_encode($query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

If you are truly only returning a single column (`totalHoursWorked`) without any of the other data, then I don't see the need to involve the `user_info` table at all.

Comment: I added the db-fiddle link: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/vpozKbVoXxPoGzcsBkLL36/0

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

> `$sql = "SELECT id, firstName, middleName, lastName FROM users_info";`

and

> ```
> "SELECT CAST(SUM(timediff(dateTimeOut, dateTimeIn)) 
>                  as time) as totalHoursWorked
>                  FROM users_time WHERE user_id = {$row['id']}"
> ```

can be merged into a single query:

```
   SELECT r.id, r.totalHoursWorked, t.firstName, t.middleName, t.lastName 
   FROM (
      SELECT q.id, SUM(q.hoursWorked) as totalHoursWorked 
      FROM (
          SELECT 
              id
            , timestampdiff(second, dateTimeIn, dateTimeOut) / 3600.0 as hoursWorked
          FROM users_info
          INNER JOIN users_time ON user_id = id
          ) q
      GROUP BY id
      ) r
    INNER JOIN users_info t on t.id = r.id;
```

Yielding:

```
id  totalHoursWorked    firstName   middleName  lastName
1   0.3                 Isabelle    Luna        Ibarra
2   0.3                 George      Boston      Everett
3   0.15                Skyler      Land        Cohen
```

Comment: It's only returning a single row
`[{"id":40,"firstName":"Employee 406","middleName":"Generated","lastName":"Auto","totalHoursWorked":"225:00:00"}]`

instead of this:


`[{"id":40,"firstName":"Employee 406","middleName":"Generated","lastName":"Auto","totalHoursWorked":"09:00:00"},{"id":41,"firstName":"Employee 692","middleName":"Generated","lastName":"Auto","totalHoursWorked":"152:00:00"},{"id":42,"firstName":"Employee 399","middleName":"Generated","lastName":"Auto","totalHoursWorked":"64:00:00"}]` Basically, it was adding all the rows in the table.

Comment: @Gene Adrian San Luis Your timediff was not outputted in hours.